# Bootstrap 3 columns to 2 rows

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a row with 3 cols. In small devices I want to turn it into two cols in the "first row" and 1 centered col in the "second row" just like a reverse pyramid.

Is it possible?

I tried using some answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18258774/organising-a-3-column-to-2-column-in-twitter-bootstrap-3) what has worked but when I go back to larger screens things get messy.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <figure class="box-1">
        <img class="services-imgs" src="images/page1-img01.jpg" alt="rehab" />
        <figcaption class="figcaption"><a href="serviços.html">Reabilitação Vestibular</a></figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <figure class="box-1">    
        <img class="services-imgs" src="images/page1-img02.jpg" alt="drenagem" />
        <figcaption class="figcaption"><a href="serviços.html">Fisioterapia Estética</a></figcaption>
    </figure>          
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <figure class="box-1">
        <img class="services-imgs" src="images/traumato.jpg" alt="traumato-ortopédica" />
        <figcaption class="figcaption"><a href="serviços.html">Fisioterapia Traumato-Ortopédica</a></figcaption>
    </figure>            
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can make specific changes via media queries into a separate CSS file in order to make this work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change `col-sm-6` to `col-xs-6` (it will apply to x-small and small screens)

Then remove the `col-lg-4` as it is not needed (the class `col-md-4` applies from medium to all bigger sizes, unless specified differently)

Having done that, you can simply add an offset to the last column like this:
`class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 col-md-4 col-md-offset-0"`

Basically, if `xs` offset it by 3 columns (which then centers it) and it removes the offset for medium or higher screens.

**See demo below**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
    <figure class="box-1">
      <img class="services-imgs" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300" alt="rehab" />
      <figcaption class="figcaption"><a href="serviços.html">Reabilitação Vestibular</a>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
    <figure class="box-1">
      <img class="services-imgs" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300" alt="drenagem" />
      <figcaption class="figcaption"><a href="serviços.html">Fisioterapia Estética</a>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 col-md-4 col-md-offset-0">
    <figure class="box-1">
      <img class="services-imgs" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300" alt="traumato-ortopédica" />
      <figcaption class="figcaption"><a href="serviços.html">Fisioterapia Traumato-Ortopédica</a>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Beat me by 2 seconds :D. But yours is better.

Comment: Ok, It works fine but in screens like the smartphones I need just 1 col with 3 "rows". So I had to keep **<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-4 col-md-offset-0">** . Thank u all :)

Comment: then you can always say `col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-4 col-md-offset-0` to differentiate `XS` from `SM` screens

Answer (score 2):

Note: For a more in-depth solution, see ochi's answer.

I think you want something like this:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">First</div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">Second</div>
  <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6 col-md-offset-0 col-md-4">Third</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

You don't need any custom CSS with this code.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```css
div{
  background: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">1</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">2</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">3</div>
</div>
```

You just need to specify the behavior depending on the screen size, e.g. `col-md-4 col-sm-6`

Comment: This changes the width of the last column on smaller screens (which may or may not be a desirable outcome)

Answer (score 0):

In your lines `<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">`, the 'sm', 'md', and 'lg' correspond to small, medium and large devices. There is a total of 12 'segments' to work with, and Bootstrap will handle all of the changes for you automatically in that regard.

As you're using a width of 4 for 3 columns for medium and large devices, there shouldn't be any problems on a large device. If there are problems, it's because you've added your own negative margins somewhere. Check for that.

To have it display like a reverse pyramind, you'll need to centralise the third result. For your first two columns you want `<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">`. For your third column, you'll want `col-sm-12` to ensure that it occupies the full width (with no other columns) on a mobile device. Then you'll need to turn the first child of that column to a 50% width. In this case, that's `<figure>`.

```
.col-md-4:nth-of-type(3) figure {
    width: 50%;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Hope this helps!